# How to hide the list view and show another layout in android?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I Have a listview with simple adapter if i click the listview item the listview shoud hide and another layout shoud show

I have tryed so for
ListView Code

```
    final String[] questions = new String[] {
       "1. What was banned in 393 A.D. as it was considered an unholy ritual by the Romans?", 
      "2. The musical instrument ‘veena’ is made from the wood of which tree?",
      "3. The movie Jurassic Park was based on a novel of the same name. Can you name the author?", 
      "4. Which famous personality was assassinated on 31st October 1984 by Satwant Singh and Beant Singh?", 
      "5. Who owns the newspaper Saakshi and used it to campaign in the media?", 
      "6. The filament of a common light bulb is generally made from which material?", 
      "7. Who was the last Tsar (king) of Russia who along with his entire family was murdered in the Russian revolution in 1917?", 
      "8. Who in Indian sports is known as the Flying Sikh?", 
      "9. In internet terminology we often come across the term URL. What does URL stand for?", 
     "10. In world of children literature, who is the famous sister of Anastasia and Drizella?" };

     for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

        HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp.put("question", questions[i]);
        TotalQuestion.add(temp);
    }
    SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
                         TotalQuestion, R.layout.activity_question, new String[] {
                         "question" }, new int[] { R.id.text_question });
    lv.setAdapter(sa);`
```

And i am trying to hide the listview in listview onItemclick
Code to hide the listview is

```
    View myView = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);//linearLayout1 Contains listview textbox
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) myView.getParent();
    parent.removeView(myView);

    LinearLayout hiddenLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);
            if (hiddenLayout == null) {
                // Inflate the Hidden Layout Information View
                LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
                View hiddenInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.hidden, myLayout, false);
                myLayout.addView(hiddenInfo);
            }
```

Comment: why you want hide `listView`? why don't open another layout in one step?

Comment: The question in listview and if i click the listview the answer page should display so only i need this

Answer (score 0):

if you want change layout you can call `setContentView();`again in every where you want(in your app this must called on item select of list), but in your scenarios I think you need position of your list in other activity, so create another class and call the class with intent, and pass your data with that.